# create ilnked list from input array

Tags: java, linked-list

I am trying to create linked list from input  int array[].
How i have to iterate to create linked list?

```
class ListNode<T>{
  Integer value;
  ListNode<Integer> next;

  ListNode(Integer x) {
    value = x;
  }
}
int input[] = {2,4,5,7,4,9,6,3,8,4,1};
```

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: If you don't know how to loop over an array, you shouldn't try to create a generic linked list. Learn what left and right mean before trying to drive a car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to transfer data from the array to the linked list, just do it in a specific for loop after the array index.
If I did not help, specify your question;)